# Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue debug

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my Swift app (which obviously has ARC enabled), I get "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" after allocating 5 CMSampleBuffers. How do I debug which part of the code is retaining the objects?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: It's a long code, but I want to know how to know where buffers can be retained. How do I use XCode tools to locate the places holding buffers?

Comment: Updated the question with code

Answer (score 1):

> How do I debug which part of the code is retaining the objects?

You would use Instruments and the Allocations template.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, storing large data files or too many images caused the Memory issue. That may be your problem. However, I'm not completely sure.